# Textbox Tag Style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I'm not sure what is the correct term for this style but, can this style be possible in WPF textbox? More often, I see this here in this community when you asked a question and you are mandatory to put a **Tags**.

**Sample Textbox Output**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Tokenizing Control – Convert Text to Tokens](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/) Most of the work has already been done there you just need to modify the template according to what and how you wanted to show the controls

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Works great!

I have one question. How do I implement TokenMatcher if my strings are coming from an array? For now, it format every word when you type semicolon(;) in the textbox. But how about when you click a button and read some string array?

Thanks

Comment: you may use `Split` to get the string from the array or probably run a foreach loop for getting all the elements of the Array

Comment: I still don't get it how do I trigger the formatting of text when I click the button.

`private void btnCompliant_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Tokenizer.AppendText("tag1;tag2");
        }`

Comment: ask a different question with the code you have written. And comment me the link to follow. So that I can try to help you specifically